# AWS EC2 100% CPU utilization

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I try to host my product to AWS EC2 service and I faced with a problem.

My service is a Node.js app. It do some CPU intensive initialization after start. It stucks after about a 30 sec of work any time I started it. I added detailed logs of the app execution and according them looks like app is totally hung on. However CPU usage is 100%.

I've tried to run the app on many different types of instances. The last try is running on `c5n.xlarge` instance. OS is Ubuntu 18.04. In all cases my app is stuck. Meanwhile, my app perfectly works on Heroku Free and Hobby dynos (https://www.heroku.com/pricing) and on my local PC with Core i5-3450 CPU.

What the problem might be?

Comment: Maybe it tries to access internet or some other resource and can't, so it hangs on it.

Comment: No, there are no any network operations. But there are reading/parsing a lot of xml files located in EBS General Purpose SSD volume. May be intensive I/O operations with the volume is the reason of the problem?

Comment: Yes. gp2 is burstable type of ebs. If you do lots of intensive I/O you may use up all your credits (check metrics). Increase gp2 size to get more credits or change to io1.

Comment: Thank you. But looks like it is not a reason of my problem. Init phase is a reading (i/o operation) and parsing (cpu operation) a lot of xml files. I tried to temporary disable parsing step and the init phase is successfully finished. So, imho, i/o operations are not a reason. However, when I uncomment parsing phase - the process has stucked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not linked to AWS EC2. The reason was usage an unstable version of module under the concrete Node.js version.